# Regular expression to match any word followed by a literal string

Tags: regex, tcl

So I have the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\b(myword+-)\b*
```

which I thought would match

- `^` start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` any alpha character
- `+` of one or more characters
- `\b` followed by a word break
- `(myword+-)` followed by myword which could include one or more special characters
- `\b` followed by a word break
- `\*` followed by anything at all

One: it does not work - it does not match anything

Two: any special characters included in `{myword+-)` throws an error

I could escape the special characters, but I don't know in advance what they might be, so I would have to escape all the possibilites, or perhaps I could just escape every character in `{\m\y\w\o\r\d\\+\\-)`

*Edited to add:*

Sorry, I knew I should have given more information

I have a series of strings to seach through in the form:

extra android-sdk and more that is of no interest
extra android-ndk and more that is of no interest
extra anjuta-extra and more that is of no interest
community c++-gtk-utils and more that is of no interest

and I have a list of items to search for in the strings:

android-sdk
android-ndk
extra
c++-gtk-utils

The item should only match if the second word in the string is an exact match to the item, so:

android-sdk will match the first string
android-ndk will match the second string
extra wuill NOT match the third string
c++-gtk-utils will match the fourth string

So (myword+-) is the item I am searching for "which could include one or more special characters"

Thanks for the help

Andrew

Comment: `myword+-` says "myword" followed by 0 or more `d`, followed by a `-`

Comment: What are you trying to match against? A couple of test cases would be useful.

Comment: Are you trying to use a variable inside a regex pattern?

Comment: Oh my... Your understanding of regex special characters is quite wrong. Perhaps use a site like Regex101 or similiar to test your regexes? You also get regex breakdown on the right side of the site so you could see what your errors are.

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually, to be exact, its `1 or more` "d", since it's a plus sign ;) But good note still.

Comment: @Asunez I wrote it correctly. The first d is part of `word`

Comment: @cricket_007 It is not. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/xjtaUK/1). Third line does not match.

Comment: @Asunez Obviously. There's no d. It's not "myword followed by 0 or more d"...

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, now I get what you wanted to say :) You meant that the first "d" is already in the word, but I thought you were referring to OPs regex, not your comment. Looks like we were both right, but thinking of different things.

Answer (score 0):

OK, with the help from above I worked it out.

This regex does exactly what I wanted, bear in mind that I am working in tcl (note the spaces to delimit the search word):

^[a-zA-Z]+\y extra \y *

where the search word is "extra".

It is necessary to escape any characters in the search string which may be interpreted by regex as qualifiers etc e.g +

So this will also work:

^[a-zA-Z]+\y dbus-c\+\+ \y *

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Strong recommendation: if you want to match literal strings, don't use regular expressions.

If we have this sample data:

```
set strings {
    {extra android-sdk and more that is of no interest}
    {extra android-ndk and more that is of no interest}
    {extra anjuta-extra and more that is of no interest}
    {community c++-gtk-utils and more that is of no interest}
}

set search_strings {
    android-sdk
    android-ndk
    extra
    c++-gtk-utils
}
```

Then, to find matches in the 2nd word of each string, we'll just use the `eq` string equality operator

```
foreach string $strings {
    foreach search $search_strings {
        if {[lindex [split $string] 1] eq $search} {
            puts "$search matches $string"
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
android-sdk matches extra android-sdk and more that is of no interest
android-ndk matches extra android-ndk and more that is of no interest
c++-gtk-utils matches community c++-gtk-utils and more that is of no interest
```

If you insist on regular expression matching, you can escape any special characters to take away their usual regex meaning. Here, we'll take the brute force approach: any non-word chars will get escaped, so that the pattern may look like `^\S+\s+c\+\+\-gtk\-utils`

```
foreach string $strings {
    foreach search $search_strings {
        set pattern "^\\S+\\s+[regsub -all {\W} $search {\\&}]"
        if {[regexp $pattern $string]} {
            puts "$search matches $string"
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to be able to  make a **portion** of a regular expression to be a literal string, like

```
set pattern "^\\S+\\s+(***=$string)"
set pattern "^\\S+\\s+((?q)$string)"
```

but both failed.

Tcl regular expressions are documented at
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Also note your pattern `^[a-zA-Z]+\b(myword+-)\b*` does not provide for any whitespace between the first and second words.

Comment: That is a very nice solution, thank you. The Regex method, however, is much quicker.  The \y used instead of \b marks each word barrier, allowing therefore for whitespace.

Comment: there's no word boundary between `[A-Za-z]+` and `myword` -- that's a string of alpha chars. You need `\s+` in there to separate the first from the second word.

Comment: In my answer/solution above the regex is ^[a-zA-Z]+\y extra \y * or ^[a-zA-Z]+\y dbus-c\+\+ \y *  so you can see that I used the \y to delimit the words

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer:** Since your question lacks information what input and output is expected, I will give it a try to tell you why your Regex isn't working at all. Since it's not a full answer you might *not want* to mark it as accepted and possibly wait for someone to give you an example of working solution, as soon as you provide necessary information.

---

Notes:

- quantifier characters (*, **+**, **?** etc.) are applied to literal character or character class (a.k.a character group, namely characters/ranges inside **[ ]**) - when in your regex you write `(myword+-)` the only thing the `+` sign is applied to is letter 'd', nothing else.
- what is `myword` in your regex? If you want a set of characters use **[ ]** combined with character ranges and/or character tokens such as `\w` (all word characters, such as letters and some special characters) or `\d` (all digit characters)
- you also seem to misunderstand and misuse groups ("**`( )`**"), character classes ("**`[ ]`**") and quantifier notation ("**`{ }`**")

Comment: `\b` is a backspace.  This is Tcl.  `\y` would be appropriate.

Comment: @BradLanam Okay, I haven't noticed the Tcl tag. I will remove this point to not cause chaos. Are other notes OK in context of Tcl?

Comment: The rest are fine in Tcl context.